# What happened to Py_FlushLine in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, c, api, python-3.x

I'm porting a python C module from 2.7.x over to python 3.3. One of the issues I ran into is that `Py_FlushLine` isn't defined in the python headers from what I can tell.

How should the following code snippet be modified to work in python 3.3?

```
  if (Py_FlushLine()) PyErr_Clear();
```

What's more interesting is that searching the online python docs doesn't show anything about this `Py_FlushLine` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Py_Flushline` used to look like this:

```
int
Py_FlushLine(void)
{
       PyObject *f = PySys_GetObject("stdout");
       if (f == NULL)
               return 0;
       if (!PyFile_SoftSpace(f, 0))
               return 0;
       return PyFile_WriteString("\n", f);
}
```

Since Py3k no longer has the concept of softspace, I'm guessing the decision was that this function was redundant and one should just write the EOL to stdout directly.